# The last character doesn't print

Tags: python, string, range

I am trying to write a code that will return the longest substring with consecutive characters out of a string.

This is my code:

```
s = 'abcecdefgh'
n = 1
string_l = ''
string_s = str(s[0])

for char in range(0,(len(s)-1)):
    if s[n]>s[n-1] and n+1 < (len(s)):     
        string_s += str(s[n])
        n +=1
    else:

        #string_s += str(s[n+1])
        if len(string_s)> len(string_l):
            string_l = string_s
            string_s = str(s[n])
            n += 1
        else:
            n += 1



print(string_l)
```

It "works" except that the last character doesn't print unless the value is smaller than the previous one.

In my case, when s = 'abcecdefgh', the output is "cdefg". 
If s = 'abcecdefgh', then the output is 'cdefgh'.

And I don't understand why!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, if your input is `abcecdefghxx` the output is `cdefghx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check your code to see where **this** error comes from, as there are several problems with it, instead I created a new implementation:

*script.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def substring_original(s):
    n = 1
    string_l = ''
    string_s = str(s[0])

    for char in range(0, (len(s) - 1)):
        if s[n] > s[n - 1] and n + 1 < (len(s)):
            string_s += str(s[n])
            n += 1
        else:
            #string_s += str(s[n+1])
            if len(string_s) > len(string_l):
                string_l = string_s
                string_s = str(s[n])
                n += 1
            else:
                n += 1
    return string_l


def substring(s):
    l = len(s)
    max_sub_len = 0
    max_sub_idx = -1
    for idx in range(l):
        cur_len = 0
        idx1 = idx + 1
        while idx1 < l and ord(s[idx1]) - ord(s[idx1 - 1]) == 1:
            idx1 += 1
        cur_sub_len = idx1 - idx
        if cur_sub_len > max_sub_len:
            max_sub_len = cur_sub_len
            max_sub_idx = idx
    return s[max_sub_idx:max_sub_idx + max_sub_len]


def main():
    for s in [
        "abcecdefgh",
        "abcecdefgg",
        "abcecdxefxgh",
        "ab",
        "cba",
        "a",
        "",
    ]:
        try:
            orig_substr = substring_original(s)
        except Exception as e:
            orig_substr = str(e)
        try:
            new_substr = substring(s)
        except Exception as e:
            new_substr = str(e)
        print(f"\nText: [{s}]\n    Original substring: [{orig_substr}]\n    New substring: [{new_substr}]")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- The code (including yours) is organized in functions
- The new implementation (*substring*):

  - Does the trick, but it's not very efficient, as same string operations (compares) are executed more than one time, so there's room for improvement
  - There cases when a string contains multiple substrings with the same (maximum) length. In this case, the 1<sup>st</sup> one is returned
- At the end, some tests are attempted on several string examples

**Output**:

```bat
[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057025425]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" script.py
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32


Text: [abcecdefgh]
    Original substring: [cdefg]
    New substring: [cdefgh]

Text: [abcecdefgg]
    Original substring: [cdefg]
    New substring: [cdefg]

Text: [abcecdxefxgh]
    Original substring: [cdxfx]
    New substring: [abc]

Text: [ab]
    Original substring: [a]
    New substring: [ab]

Text: [cba]
    Original substring: [c]
    New substring: [c]

Text: [a]
    Original substring: []
    New substring: [a]

Text: []
    Original substring: [string index out of range]
    New substring: []

Done.
```